# gnome window switches and password fields

Tags: pygtk, gtk, gnome, xlib

I wrote a small key logger for Ubuntu, but I don't want it to record specific windows or password fields (in all windows). So I need some way to:

1. Detect when a new window gets focus (so that I can stop my logging if needed).
2. Detect when the user enters a password field (again, so that I could stop my logging).

Any ideas?

Comment: And you're planning to snoop on who...? Unless you explicitly say this isn't a **Black Hat** activity, you won't get a lot of help.

Comment: You'd probably do better to *whitelist* the window(s) to which you want to listen. Or just listen to your own events.